# One way ANOVA or chi-squared testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I face problem in the following exercise:
"In the professional football championship, it was said that during the last eight years, there was a discriminatory treatment of the team1, in relation to the other two equivalent team2 and team3. You argue in this regard according to the data presented in the attached photo?" I face difficulty to recognise if it is one way anova problem or chi-squared? I would appreciate for your quidance. Thank you very much in advance. [image: exercise data]

Comment: Did you mean c*h*i-squared testing?

Comment: Τhat' s right. Thank you very much! Is it chi-squared testing or something else?